# Store the string values in Keychain Access with out Using external class in obj c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, keychain

Using **KeychainItemWrapper** classes successfully Stored values. But
Want to Store the string values in Keychain Access with out Using external class in obj c. How can implement. Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 0):

check the above link for store the values without external classes

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/simple-iphone-keychain-access/